# I'd like to change menu on My Account page

Tags: menu, file

[image]

I'd like to hide several menu on MY Account page to my customers.
So I tried to change navigation.phtml file, 
but I couldn't find the menu on MY Accout page.

The file was written like this

```
<div class="block-content">
    <ul>
        <?php $_links = $this->getLinks(); ?>
        <?php $_index = 1; ?>
        <?php $_count = count($_links); ?>
        <?php foreach ($_links as $_link): ?>
            <?php $_last = ($_index++ >= $_count); ?>
            <?php if ($this->isActive($_link)): ?>
                <li class="current<?php echo ($_last ? ' last' : '') ?>"><strong><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></strong></li>
            <?php else: ?>
                <li<?php echo ($_last ? ' class="last"' : '') ?>><a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></a></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I think I have to change other file instead of navigation.phtml

Where the file having an effect on this menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All menu for account section are defined in layout xml's under reference name="customer_account_navigation".

Some example are :

Billing Agreements : 
copy this file 
`app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales/billing_agreement.xml`
in your current theme and remove below lines

```
<reference name="customer_account_navigation" >
    <action method="addLink" translate="label"><name>billing_agreements</name><path>sales/billing_agreement/</path><label>Billing Agreements</label></action>
</reference>
```

Recurring Profiles : 
copy this file 
`app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales/recurring_profile.xml`
in your current theme and remove below lines

```
<reference name="customer_account_navigation" >
        <action method="addLink" translate="label"><name>recurring_profiles</name><path>sales/recurring_profile/</path><label>Recurring Profiles</label></action>
    </reference>
```

My Downloadable Products : 
copy this file 
`app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/downloadable.xml`
in your current theme and remove below lines

```
<reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="downloadable"><name>downloadable_products</name><path>downloadable/customer/products</path><label>My Downloadable Products</label></action>
    </reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your theme local.xml add below code with this code first remove your navigation and then add links that you want to display :

```
<customer_account translate="label">
    <reference name="left">
        <!--Unset the whole block then add back later-->
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>customer_account_navigation</name></action>
        <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Information</label></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>orders</name><path>sales/order/history/</path><label>My Orders</label></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="review"><name>reviews</name><path>review/customer</path><label>My Product Reviews</label></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="wishlist" ifconfig="wishlist/general/active"><name>wishlist</name><path>wishlist/</path><label>My Favorite</label></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="newsletter"><name>newsletter</name><path>newsletter/manage/</path><label>Newsletter Subscriptions</label></action>
        </block>
        <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar"/>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to override navigation file,
so add this code in config xml:

```
<customer>
  <rewrite>
       <account_navigation>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Account_Navigation</account_navigation>
  </rewrite>
</customer>
```

Then create Folder Mynamespace/Mymodule/Block/Account /Navigation.php
and add below code:

```
public function removeLinkByName($name)
{
    unset($this->_links[$name]);
    return $this;
}
```

Open xml file in layout folder than add below code:

```
<customer_account translate="label">
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>billing_agreements</name></action>
        <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>recurring_profiles</name></action>
        <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>tags</name></action>
        <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>wishlist</name></action>
        <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>OAuth Customer Tokens</name></action>
        <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>downloadable_products</name></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

Comment: For more details follow this link: http://inchoo.net/magento/managing-navigation-links/